# How to undo "git commit --amend" done instead of "git commit"

Tags: git, commit, undo, git-amend

I accidentally amended my previous commit. The commit should have been separate to keep history of the changes I made to a particular file.

Is there a way to undo that last commit? If I do something like `git reset --hard HEAD^`, the first commit also is undone.

(I have not yet pushed to any remote directories)

Comment: *if* you want to confirm the effects of each step you took (either before trying out the answers below or if your head starts to spin while executing one) try `git log --reflog -p -- {{name-of-the-dir-or-file-in-question}}`. It shows both the actual changes and the commit messages for each action.

Answer (score 3419, accepted):

What you need to do is to create a new commit with the same details as the current `HEAD` commit, but with the parent as the previous version of `HEAD`. `git reset --soft` will move the branch pointer so that the next commit happens on top of a different commit from where the current branch head is now.

```bash
# Move the current head so that it's pointing at the old commit
# Leave the index intact for redoing the commit.
# HEAD@{1} gives you "the commit that HEAD pointed at before 
# it was moved to where it currently points at". Note that this is
# different from HEAD~1, which gives you "the commit that is the
# parent node of the commit that HEAD is currently pointing to."
git reset --soft HEAD@{1}

# commit the current tree using the commit details of the previous
# HEAD commit. (Note that HEAD@{1} is pointing somewhere different from the
# previous command. It's now pointing at the erroneously amended commit.)
# The -C option takes the given commit and reuses the log message and
# authorship information.
git commit -C HEAD@{1}
```

Comment: Very cool, +1. I even did it with the second last amend view into `git reflog` to find the correct number e.g. `{2}`.

Comment: Just to be clear, the first command is a true "undo". It produces the HEAD, working directory (unchanged), and index state prior to `git commit --amend`. The 2nd is a "redo" into a new commit. These work for any `git commit`, not just `--amend`.

Comment: So if you didn't amend with a new commit message that you need to salvage, the second part can just be a regular `git commit`.

Comment: For some reason, I was getting an error when running `git reset --soft HEAD@{1}`: `fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD@1': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions`. When I replaced `HEAD@{1}` with the equivalent commit hash shown in `git reflog` (thanks JJD!), this answer worked wonderfully!

Comment: @TimArnold depending on your shell, you may need to put single or double quotes around `HEAD@{1}`. If I run `echo HEAD@{1}` in tcsh for example, the output is `HEAD@1` because the braces were interpreted by tcsh. If I use single quotes, the braces are preserved.

Comment: yeap, you need quotes around `HEAD@{1}` in `tcsh`; won't work otherwise

Comment: That first line saved my ass (git reset --soft HEAD@{1} to undo the commit --amend). Thanks!

Comment: @demisx: No, `HEAD@{1}` and `HEAD^1` are NOT the same. Understanding `HEAD@{1}` and `reflog` is the crux of the solution here.  Compare `git reflog` which `HEAD@{1}` is referencing VS. `git log` the commit history that  `HEAD^1` is referencing.  

The reflog is actually a lot simpler (as it is linear or least the referencing of it is) vs. the the commit history which could be tree like with more complicated referencing.  If you want to dig deeper down that rabbit hole checkout `HEAD~` vs `HEAD^`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221658/whats-the-difference-between-head-and-head-in-git

Comment: I lost the changes I amended into the commit amend though. Help!

Comment: doing `git reflog` will show you a list of things you had done - helpful if you have done some other things since the 'amend' - `HEAD@{1}` refers to the most recent action

Comment: If using powershell, you will have to escape the squiggly braces with back-ticks.

Comment: What if it was at rebase edit command? How to return original commit information, message, committer, etc?

Comment: reset is by default soft so `--soft` is not needed here. Also maybe add those ticks around the `HEAD@{1}` bit for shell safety. So `git reset 'HEAD@{1}'`

Comment: The default for `reset` is `--mixed`, not `--soft`. `HEAD@{1}` is Bourne shell safe. Bourne shell and its variants are the most popular shells used with Git, people using other shells may need to make adjustments as making an answer portable to every conceivable shell probably isn't practical.

Comment: It might be helpful to follow up with a `git commit --amend --reset-author` to set the author of your commit to yourself. In my case I had by mistake ammended to the last commit by author A and when resetting and committing as explained above, the author of my commit was still A.

Comment: Can someone explain why the second statement (git commit -C) is needed?

Comment: I had to also do a (git rebase) in the end

Comment: I did commit --amend on the merge commit, resulting in the real merge commit hidden. I ran the two suggested commands but they didn't seem to have any effect. git log still shows the amended merge commit as though it were the merge commit. The real merge commit is there as a reference to remote branch (because I pushed) but it isn't referencing my local branch. How do I restore the real merge commit as part of my local branch?

Comment: I just did the first command to restore to the state I needed. Thanks for this, realizing just how useful the reflog really is.

Comment: For future readers: if you get `error: unknown switch 'e'` you are probably runing in Powershell (Core/6?). EIther backtick the right stuff as mentioned above or switch to a legacy command prompt.

Comment: @Jonathan `-C` in `git commit -C HEAD@{1}` reuses the message from the commit given.
See man git-commit:
`-C <commit>, --reuse-message=<commit>
           Take an existing commit object, and reuse the log message and the
           authorship information (including the timestamp) when creating the
           commit.`

Comment: @KentMuntheCaspersen I had the same problem, but followed up with `git reset HEAD~1`, `git add`, `git commit` instead. I suppose `--reset-author` is the way to go though.

Comment: @Zyl for some reasons the command `git reset --soft HEAD@{1}` didn't work on my mac but `git reset HEAD~1` worked. thanks

Comment: This didn't work but @kenorb's answer (with `cherry-pick`) did.

Comment: Just wondering why this answer is way below when it has lot of votes, I thought Stackoverflow now sorts answers by score?

Comment: In my opinion, the second command is introducing confusion into an otherwise great answer. The question is about undoing an accidental amend. That's what the first command addresses. Whether you'd want the new commit to have the same commit message is a separate issue (and I really don't know why you'd want that if you've accidentally amended). You can simply just `git commit` after the first command.

Comment: I don't see why you would suggest using the `-C`-option here. It wasn't asked for if I understand correctly...

Answer (score 212):

Use the [ref-log](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-emltrefnamegtltngtemegemmaster1em):

```
git branch fixing-things HEAD@{1}
git reset --soft fixing-things
```

You should then have all your previously amended changes in your working copy and can commit them to a new commit.

To see a full list of previous head commits type [`git reflog`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reflog.html).

You might find my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77327251/112968) helpful if you are looking for a single command to achieve this and are not afraid of low-level plumbing commands.

Comment: This wipes the index too -- still useful, but goes beyond a simple "undo".

Comment: @neaumusic: yes! `HEAD~1` is exactly the same as `HEAD^` and identifiers the _parent_ of the current commit. `HEAD@{1}` on the other hand refers to the commit which HEAD pointed to before this one, i.e. they mean different commits when you checkout a different branch or amend a commit.

Comment: @knittl ah no wonder i didnt think this was possible before, thanks again, good information

Comment: the fist step is redundant. Simple `git reset HEAD@{1}` is enough.

Comment: @jamesdeath123 he's simply creating a new branch from a previous commit, and then resetting the main branch to the new branch. He gains nothing by this.

Comment: Creating a temporary branch helps to give commits a name and to not mess up things further :)

Comment: WOW, `reflog` means `ref-log` and not `re-flog`? This makes so much more sense

Answer (score 210):

None of these answers with the use of `HEAD@{1}` worked out for me, so here's my solution:

`git reflog`

```
d0c9f22 HEAD@{0}: commit (amend): [Feature] - ABC Commit Description 
c296452 HEAD@{1}: commit: [Feature] - ABC Commit Description
```

`git reset --soft c296452`

Your staging environment will now contain all of the changes that you accidentally merged with the c296452 commit.

Comment: I executed ```git commit --amend``` on an already pushed commit and therefore the other suggestions did not work. But this did. Thanks.

Comment: Nice. So I just did `git reset --soft HEAD@{1}` to cancel the latest amend.

Comment: If you're in powershell, `git reset --soft "HEAD@{1}"` needs to have quotes. `{1}` is special syntax it seems like

Comment: Thx, because the accepted solution did absolutely nothing in my repo

Comment: This is the most straightforward answer for me to understand. When doing potentially dangerous things in git, I prefer to use an explicit commit reference instead of relative reference like `HEAD@{1}`, which could be referencing something different than what I intended.

Answer (score 141):

Find your amended commits by:

```
git log --reflog
```

<sup>Note: You may add `--patch` to see the body of the commits for clarity. Same as `git reflog`.</sup>

then reset your HEAD to any previous commit at the point it was fine by:

```
git reset SHA1 --hard
```

<sup>Note: **Replace** SHA1 with your real commit hash. Also note that this command will **lose** any uncommitted changes, so you may stash them before. Alternatively, **use `--soft` instead to retain the latest changes** and then commit them.</sup>

Then cherry-pick the other commit that you need on top of it:

```
git cherry-pick SHA1
```

Comment: If you do `git reset SHA1 --soft`, you can retain the latest changes and then commit them.

Comment: and another handy trick: *if*, before messing around, you want to confirm the effects of each step you took, try `git log --reflog -p -- {{name-of-the-dir-or-file-in-question}}`. It shows both the actual changes and the commit messages.

Comment: Just use `git reset SHA1`, which defaults to mode `--mixed` which doesn't reset the working tree, allowing you to commit right away. `git reset SHA1 && git commit -m "abc"`

Comment: @Meuko but `reset --soft` has the benefit (as I see it in this scenario) of putting the changes back in the index (not in the working tree). This way you're sure, if you commit again, you'll be committing the same changes as the commit you just reset it. This is handy to me when I amend a commit by mistake.

Comment: Full command: `git reset --soft 'HEAD@{1}'`

Answer (score 35):

If you have pushed the commit to remote and then erroneously amended changes to that commit this will fix your problem. Issue a `git log` to find the SHA before the commit. (this assumes remote is named origin). Now issue these command using that SHA.

```
git reset --soft <SHA BEFORE THE AMMEND>
#you now see all the changes in the commit and the amend undone

#save ALL the changes to the stash
git stash

git pull origin <your-branch> --ff-only
#if you issue git log you can see that you have the commit you didn't want to amend

git stash pop
#git status reveals only the changes you incorrectly amended

#now you can create your new unamended commit
```

Comment: This is a special case of the more general question, but it covered my immediate need exactly.

Comment: Same for me. I occasionally get conflicts during git rebase, and sometimes I do "amend" instead of "rebase --continue" ... and this here is just a life saver!

Answer (score 28):

Possibly worth noting that if you're still in your editor with the commit message, you can delete the commit message and it will abort the `git commit --amend` command.

Answer (score 26):

You can always split a commit,
From the [manual](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase)

- Start an interactive rebase with git rebase -i commit^, where commit is the commit you want to split. In fact, any commit range will do, as long as it contains that commit.
- Mark the commit you want to split with the action "edit".
- When it comes to editing that commit, execute git reset HEAD^. The effect is that the HEAD is rewound by one, and the index follows suit. However, the working tree stays the same.
- Now add the changes to the index that you want to have in the first commit. You can use git add (possibly interactively) or git-gui (or both) to do that.
- Commit the now-current index with whatever commit message is appropriate now.
- Repeat the last two steps until your working tree is clean.
- Continue the rebase with git rebase --continue.

Comment: way too complicated. `git reflog` is all you need

Comment: Lots of steps yes, but each step is uncomplicated and easy to do. This worked for me and gets my vote.

Comment: additionally, this answer allows you to selectively pick the changes that you accidentally 'amended', to does provide some additional value to the git reset --soft HEAD@{1} approach (which did solve my problem BTW)

Comment: You can selectively pick changes with the reflog method, too. Just do `git reset` instead of `git reset --soft`, then do `git add --patch`.

Comment: Way too complicated, and provides more control than needed to just undo a mistaken amend, which was what the question asked - not how to manually split a commit. If I mistakenly did an amend, I don't want to have to go through and select which changes I want in each commit! `git reflog` is where it's at.

Comment: This still rewrites history and requires a force push. Depending on your situation that may or may not be a problem.

Answer (score 23):

Maybe can use `git reflog` to get two commit before amend and after amend.

Then use `git diff before_commit_id after_commit_id > d.diff` to get diff between before amend and after amend.

Next use `git checkout before_commit_id` to back to before commit

And last use `git apply d.diff` to apply the real change you did.

That solves my problem.

Answer (score 15):

You can do below to undo your `git commit —amend`

1. `git reset --soft HEAD^`
2. `git checkout files_from_old_commit_on_branch`
3. `git pull origin your_branch_name`

====================================

Now your changes are as per previous. So you are done with the undo for `git commit —amend`

Now you can do `git push origin <your_branch_name>`, to push to the branch.

Comment: +1. Simple solutions to undo "amend". Just for better understanding, I would like to add before Step 2. (git checkout files), run `git restore --staged <YOUR_FILES>` to unstage changes.

Answer (score 8):

Almost 9 years late to this but didn't see this variation mentioned accomplishing the same thing (it's kind of a combination of a few of these, similar to to top answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/1459264/4642530).

**Search all detached heads on branch**

`git reflog show origin/BRANCH_NAME --date=relative`

Then find the SHA1 hash

**Reset to old SHA1**

`git reset --hard SHA1`

**Then push it back up.**

`git push origin BRANCH_NAME`

**Done.**

This will revert you back to the old commit entirely.

(Including the date of the prior overwritten detached commit head)

Comment: Yes, but I typically want to reset `--soft` to keep my changes. I just want it committed separately

Answer (score 4):

1. Checkout to temporary branch with last commit

   `git branch temp HEAD@{1}`
2. Reset last commit

   `git reset temp`
3. Now, you'll have all files your commit as well as previous commit. Check status of all the files.

   `git status`
4. Reset your commit files from git stage.

   `git reset myfile1.js` (so on)
5. Reattach this commit

   `git commit -C HEAD@{1}`
6. Add and commit your files to new commit.

Answer (score 4):

Simple Solution
**Solution Works Given**: If your HEAD commit is in sync with remote commit.

- Create one more branch in your local workspace, and keep it in sync with your remote branch.
- Cherry pick the HEAD commit from the branch (where git commit --amend) was performed onto the newly created branch.

The cherry-picked commit will only contain your latest changes, not the old changes.
You can now just rename this commit.

Comment: Great idea, worked well for me. Also note you could use `master` / `main` if no one else has merged to it yet. Saved me today!

Answer (score 3):

This is how you can do it easily:

- Soft reset the last commit which has old commit & amended changes

`git reset --soft HEAD^`

- Now commit the staged changes in a new commit

`git commit -m "new commit msg"`

Now push the changes and rebase this commit on top of last commit on which you had amended your changes.

This will make sure that the new commit has only amended changes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the low-level `commit-tree` command and the [reflog](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) to construct a new commit with your current head commit's tree, but the original (pre-amend) commit as parent. The branch is forwarded by resetting both working tree and index:

```
git reset --soft "$(git commit-tree HEAD^{tree} -p HEAD@{1} -m 'Commit message of new commit')"
```

Why does this work? Let's have a look at some ASCII drawings:

```
C     t:W    (HEAD@{1}) original commit with tree W
B     t:V
A     t:U
```

This is where we start, but after amending the commit, we are left with:

```
C'    t:X    (branch; HEAD) accidentally amended commit with tree X
| C   t:W    (HEAD@{1}) original commit with tree W
|/
B     t:V
A     t:U
```

Commit C is no longer reachable from the branch, but it still exists in Git's database and is listed in the reflog as `HEAD@{1}`.

What you want is to create the following new commit with the tree of the amended commit:

```
D     t:X    (branch; HEAD) separate commit with tree X
C     t:W    original commit with tree W
B     t:V
A     t:U
```

and `git commit-tree HEAD^{tree} -p HEAD@{1}` does exactly that: it creates commit D with tree X (same tree as of amended commit C'), but sets the parent to C (the commit before being amended). `git reset` is required to move the branch from the erroneous, amended commit to the correct, separate commit.

Comment: This one liner fixed my issue, no need to know more.