# How to list commits since certain commit?

Tags: git

Is there anyway to get a list of commits from a given commit number to HEAD?

I know this is possible by the commit date, but I need it by the commit number and I can't seem to find any documentation, or even if this is possible.

Comment: What Git command were you using to list commits from a given commit name?

Comment: You do mean commit hash, right? You can also use `HEAD~10` to mean "10 commits before HEAD" so that you can do `git log HEAD~10..`, if that's what you mean by commit number.

Answer (score 276, accepted):

```
git rev-list <since_hash>..HEAD
```

or to include the commit:

```
git rev-list <since_hash>^..HEAD
```

You can use `git log` instead of `git rev-list` as well to get additional details.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, thanks! I swear that I had tried this. Must have made a mistake.

Comment: @manojlds I know that `HEAD` is pointing to the lasted commits, but what is the meaning of `^`

Comment: @KasunSiyambalapitiya `^` is an alias for first parent. See "SPECIFYING REVISIONS" in https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-parse.html -- also see the manual https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection -- or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221658/whats-the-difference-between-head-and-head-in-git

Comment: I get a huge, huge list of SHAs... even for a commit that's just one back (one leg of a merge). What is it telling me and how is that useful?

Comment: If you just care about the *count* of commits, you can specify the `--count` option after `rev-list`. i.e.: `git rev-list --count <since_hash>..HEAD`

Comment: What if I only need certain count of commits after <since_hash> as there'd have plenty commits from <since_hash> to HEAD?

Answer (score 121):

```
git log <hash>..
```

Is the least amount of typing. Omitting "HEAD" assumes that's what you meant. Rev-list would work too.

Comment: This one is my favorite. I like to combine it with `--oneline`. Instead of `<hash>`, of course, you can use a ref like a branch name, too.

Comment: Also `git log HEAD~#..` where `#` is the number of recent commits desired.

Comment: def the best and most concise option!

Comment: It works, however it should be mentioned it behaves weirdly, I almost deemed it doesn't work. E.g. if you execute a `git log --oneline 851c30c9badf^..` in Linux kernel tree, you'll find it does not start with `851c30c9badf`, it starts instead with the most recent commit. "Alright, the `851c30c9badf` is probably at the end" one might think. Well, it isn't, it's followed by hundreds of other commits. Also, you can't use a `-5` command to see just 5 commits since the one you're interested in, not even if you pass `--reverse` arg. So depending on repo this command might give too much output.

Comment: FYI you can go the opposite way (get commits _up to_ but excluding <hash>) with `git log <hash>^@`

Comment: where `<hash>` can just as well be a branch name, so to see what changes have been made on top of `develop` for a feature branch, first `git fetch` then  `git log origin/develop..origin/feature-branch-name` for example.   No need to copy/paste those pesky hashes.

Answer (score 61):

You can run the following git command from the shell:

```
git log --pretty=oneline commit-id...HEAD
```

Answer (score 20):

Assuming that by "commit number", you mean commit hash:

```
git log <commit-hash>..HEAD
```

Answer (score 6):

If anyone here is trying to find out how to LESS through the output of `git log` starting at a certain commit, paginating backward, it's as simple as `git log <hash>`.

Answer (score 3):

Ranges like `hash..HEAD` don't seem to reliably yield the result in historical order, and options like `--author-date-order` seem to be ignored.

To get all commits *historically* since a given hash, I have found something like this to be the only correct solution (Bash):

```bash
git log --author-date-order --all --reverse --after="$(git show -s --format='%at' COMMIT_HASH)"
```

Answer (score 2):

Just adding to the answer for the general case you can get all commits from one commit to another commit. For example lets say`A` is commit hash start and `B` is commit hash end then

```
git rev-list <A>..<B>
```

for detailed

```
git log <A>..<B>
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, `git log <commit-hash>..HEAD` gets you started. `git log <commit-hash>...HEAD` is also suggested. I'm adding this answer because the number of periods can make a huge difference for diffs, so [it may be worth understanding](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/proposing-changes-to-your-work-with-pull-requests/about-comparing-branches-in-pull-requests#three-dot-and-two-dot-git-diff-comparisons) for `git log` also.

I don't understand it enough to explain it for `git log` behavior. For `git diff branchA..branchB`, the two-dot operator compares the files etc on branchB's tip to the state of files etc on branchA's tip. The three-dot operator compares the files etc on branchB's tip to the files etc in branchA at the commit where branchB diverged from branchA.

To me, this distinction can be important because three-dot might not show that similar changes were already made by some separate branch that got merged. i.e. the diff on a pull request might not show the current context of a patch to a function, if the function has changed since the branch diverged.

As an aside, GitHub, implicitly, [uses a three-dot comparison](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/proposing-changes-to-your-work-with-pull-requests/about-comparing-branches-in-pull-requests#about-three-dot-comparison-on-github) on Pull Requests. GitHub *Enterprise* also uses three-dot. As of writing this, there is a way to see how to do a two dot comparison in github on the linked pages.