# How to enumerate the set of added files to a particular directory after a given hash

Tags: git

How can I enumerate within a given repo branch the set of distinct files added to a given subdirectory since a certain commit?

Motivation: I'm trying to inspect a local copy of a public repo's source tucked away in our private repo as a third party subfolder. I'd like to ascertain what if any new files were added to that directory of our repo dedicated to the third party public repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is either fairly hard, or ridiculously easy, depending on just what you mean:

```
git diff --name-only --diff-filter=D <hash-of-B> <hash-or-branch> -- <dir>
```

---

Remember that Git stores *commits*, rather than files.  Each commit *contains* files, but each commit is otherwise an independent snapshot of *all* files—well, all files that are in that snapshot, but that's kind of a redundant and useless way to put it.  Let's just consider a tiny repository with three commits that we'll call `A`, `B`, and `C` so that we don't have to deal with big ugly hash IDs:

```
A <-B <-C   <--master
```

The branch name `master` holds the hash ID of commit `C`.  In our case we can just look at all the commits and see that `C` is obviously last, but in a real repository, with thousands of random-looking hash IDs, it's too hard, so we need someone to hold the hash ID of the *last* commit.

Commit `C` has an author name-and-email and time-stamp, a committer name-and-email-and-time-stamp, a log message, and so on.  It also holds the hash ID of commit `B`, so that we can go from `C` to `B`.  And, `C` holds all the files you want `git checkout` to put into your *work-tree* when you `git checkout master`.

Meanwhile `B` has author and committer and log message and so on, and holds the hash ID of its previous commit `A`.  For its snapshot, `B` holds all the files you want `git checkout` to put into your work-tree when you `git checkout <hash-of-B>`.

Commit `A` has the usual author/committer/log metadata.  It says that there *is no earlier commit*, so that `git log` can stop logging earlier commits for instance.  And for its snapshot, `A` holds all the files you want `git checkout` to put into your work-tree when you `git checkout <hash-of-A>`.

So: suppose you have picked out some historical commit, such as `B`, from a slightly bigger repository, with two branches `master` and `develop` and seven commits we'll call `A` through `G`, arranged like this:

```
        D--E   <-- master
       /
A--B--C
       \
        F--G   <-- develop
```

You want to know what's *different* between `B` and ... well, this is where it gets interesting.  What does

> beyond a certain commit

actually *mean*?  From `B`, we can go to `C`, if we work in the opposite direction of Git's own internal arrows.  But from `C`, we can go to *either* `D` *or* `F`, and from there to `E` (if we went to `D`) or `G` (if we went to `F`).  You need to pick a *direction*.

Having picked a direction—"in the direction of the tip of `develop`", for instance—is it OK to just compare commit `B` directly to commit `G`?  Both are complete snapshots.  Suppose `B` has files `TODO`, `d1/f1` and `d2/f2` (a total of 3 files), and `G` has files `d1/f1`, `d2/f2`, `d2/f3`, and `d3/f4` (4 files).  You can then run:

```
git diff --name-status <hash-of-B> <anything-that-finds-commit-G>
```

and Git will tell you that to change commit `B` to match commit `G`, you'd have to add (`A`) files named `d2/f3` and `d3/f4`.  It might also tell you that you'd have to modify (`M`) `d1/f1` and it would definitely tell you that you have to delete (`D`) file `TODO`.

Add to the `--name-status` a `--diff-filter` to make it print only the names of files that have some particular desired status-es.  For instance, if you want to know which files to delete and which ones to add, use `--diff-filter=AD`.  Git won't mention the files that need to be `M`odified, only those that need to be `A`dded or `D`eleted.

Replace `--name-status` with `--name-only` to keep the same output as before, minus the status letter.  Now you'll see `TODO`, `d2/f2`, and `d3/f3`, without known that `TODO` should be *deleted*.  Change `--diff-filter` to select only `D` files, and you'll no longer see `TODO`: the dropped status letter is no longer important.

Now all you need to do is limit the output to just those files whose name starts with `d2/`.  To do that, tell `git diff` to list only such files, by adding the pathspec `d2` (you can write it as `d2/` or just `d2`: if there are files named `d2/f1` and `d2/f2` there is no file *just* named `d2`: your OS can't hack that so Git won't store that).

But what if, after commit `B`—say, in `C` or `D` or `E`—someone added some file, and then *removed* that file again in commit `G`?  The above `git diff` won't tell you that.  If you want to know *that*, your job is harder.  You're going to have to look at *every commit along the path* from `B` to `G`.

What if "beyond a certain commit" means *down every path, from `B` to `G` but also from `B` to `E`*?  Then you'll have to look at all of those commits.

You must answer these questions for yourself, then choose how to diff.

Comment: Definitely a lot of subtleties I didn't consider. My thoughts were constrained to the single path diff along the repo. Didn't know about the `--diff-filter` that is a great argument. I should have listed out a concrete set of git commands to unambiguously communicate the information I was going for.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, what you are looking for is actually just a simple diff:

```
git diff your_commit:nested/path/to/dir third_party_commit:path/to/dir
```

will tell you all differences between your directory at the specified commit and the directory in the third party commit. If you are only interested in the names (and status) of changed files, you can use the `--name-status` flag to `git diff`. `--stat` might also be useful, depending on your exact use-case.

Answer (score 0):

I found a bit of a roundabout way using shell commands inspired by the following two answers: [How to list commits since certain commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7693281/1330381) and [git: list all files added/modified on a day (or week/month…)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8016702/1330381)
.

My example is taken from one of my public [repos](https://github.com/jxramos/DataApp--ParamCompare/commits/master).

```
$:DataApp--ParamCompare jxramos$ git log --name-status --pretty=format: 2f3a5c92b8d5ce31c45a6976f2e6cfa8ac79976f...HEAD | sort | uniq | grep ^A 
A   templates/data_explore_page.html
$
$
$:DataApp--ParamCompare jxramos$ git log --name-status --pretty=format: 825faef1097207479f968c6a5353e41612127849...HEAD | sort | uniq | grep ^A 
A   templates/data_explore_page.html
A   templates/plot_page.html
A   test/test_data/1.x.csv
A   test/test_data/1.y.csv
```

UPDATE

We can avoid the grep by adding the `--diff-filter=A` option. The uniq is redundant as well since file addition is a one time affair for the most part. That gives us

```
git log --name-only --diff-filter=A --pretty=format: <commitHash>...HEAD | sort | grep .
```