# git - Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit

Tags: git, push, commit

I am newbie in git and I am working on git.

I added some files in git :

```
git add <file1>
git add <file2>
```

then I wanted to push that for review, but mistakenly I did

```
git commit
```

so the files which I have changed don't go for reviews.
Now if I enter the command :

```
git status
```

it says

```
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

I want to revert that commit and I want to push those files for review rather than commit.
Can anyone let me know how I can do that?

Comment: If you want to undo your commit - take a look at the [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/git-undo-last-commit).

Comment: I don't know what you're using for code reviews. The simple answer to the simple question of how to un-commit is `git reset HEAD^`

Comment: i did reset HEAD. but then when I try to push, then it says me
D  file1.py

when I tried to psuh then again it says me that your branch is ahead of origin/master by 1 commit

Comment: What do you mean when you say "I want to push those files for review"? Do you want other people to see your commit?

Comment: my code will be first reviewed and then it will be commited. so first I want to push the code for review but mistakenly i have commited

Comment: this is confusing terminology: you have to _commit_ your code _before_ you push it. What do you mean it will be committed _after_ it's reviewed? Presumably someone else will merge it into an official repo?

Comment: (I'm sure there are many valid workflows, so what I'm about to say may not be relevant to the way your team operates...) The workflow I'm familiar with is to *commit* your changes in a "feature" or "dev" branch and *push* that to the central repository.  The "feature" branch can be merged into master after the code review.

Answer (score 165, accepted):

You cannot push anything that hasn't been committed yet. The order of operations is:

1. Make your change.
2. `git add` - this stages your changes for committing
3. `git commit` - this commits your staged changes locally
4. `git push` - this pushes your committed changes to a remote

If you push without committing, nothing gets pushed. If you commit without adding, nothing gets committed. If you add without committing, nothing at all happens, git merely remembers that the changes you added should be considered for the following commit.

The message you're seeing (your branch is ahead by 1 commit) means that your local repository has one commit that hasn't been pushed yet.

In other words: `add` and `commit` are local operations, `push`, `pull` and `fetch` are operations that interact with a remote.

Since there seems to be an official source control workflow in place where you work, you should ask internally how this should be handled.

Comment: aha ok. so it means after commit, I have to push it

Comment: Good explanation - the question'er probably doesn't want to actually revert the commit, but rather, have people review the commit before pushing it to the `origin` repository. I'd also recommend reading a few of the tutorial/intros to git on http://git-scm.com/documentation

Comment: When my git status says "Your branch is ahead of 'origin/develop' by 1 commit." how exactly do I view that files were changed? git diff doesn't seem to do anything

Comment: Sometimes is somebody else that worked there. Make a pull before your push

Answer (score 142):

`git reset HEAD^ --soft` (Save your changes, back to last commit)

`git reset HEAD^ --hard` (Discard changes, back to last commit)

Comment: What is the significance of the HEAD with a carrot '^' ? I've seen it being written without the carrot too.

Comment: I think the carrot reverts by one commit (so if you have to back up 3 commits, then you could run the command 3 times). Similarly, you could run `git reset HEAD~ --hard` to revert all commits to the HEAD

Comment: It's caret, not carrot.

Comment: See detailed discussion in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221658/whats-the-difference-between-head-and-head-in-git

Answer (score 48):

If you just want to throw away the changes and revert to the last commit (the one you wanted to share):

```
git reset --hard HEAD~
```

You may want to check to make absolutely sure you want this (`git log`), because you'll loose all changes.

A safer alternative is to run

```
git reset --soft HEAD~ # reset to the last commit
git stash              # stash all the changes in the working tree 
git push               # push changes 
git stash pop          # get your changes back
```

Answer (score 25):

I resolved this by just running a simple:

```
git pull
```

Nothing more.
Now it's showing:

```
# On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Comment: It can cause problem if there will more than one created branch which is not required.

Comment: you went back to you remote state and lost your last work :D

Answer (score 19):

git reset HEAD^

then the modified files should show up.

You could move the modified files into a new branch

use,

`git checkout -b newbranch`

`git checkout commit -m "files modified"`

`git push origin newbranch`

`git checkout master`

then you should be on a clean branch, and your changes should be stored in newbranch. You could later just merge this change into the master branch

Answer (score 4):

```
git reset HEAD <file1> <file2> ...
```

remove the specified files from the next commit

Answer (score 0):

connect to

> remote origin/master

not

> local master

and make a pull request.

Create a new branch base on remote master.