# Why is the local master branch one ahead of remote master after merge?

Tags: git

I did run these ***commands*** why is local master one ahead of remote master? and how do I resolve this problem, should I push the local to master after merging the feature branch?

```
git checkout origin release-branch
git add .  
git commit -m "some message"
git push origin release-branch

git checkout master
git merge release-branch
```

Comment: Its probably due to merge commit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, make sure that you are in the current stage of the master by pulling it to local:

```
git pull origin master
```

Then, in local its enough to checkout without mention the origin:

```
git checkout some-branch
// now do your coding changes in this branch, save, commit and push
```

Later, you should push the merged content to master as well, so:

```
git checkout master
git merge some-branch // now its locally merged to master
git push origin master // now its in the remote repo
```

To make sure and keep track of your local git repo and the remote git repo stages, use:

```
git log --oneline // oneline flag makes it easier to read
```

If you see that your working directory is BEHIND the branch you are about to work on, remember the first command of pull to make them even.

Answer (score 0):

once you push changes to `branch` and that got merge to `master` then need to get in syn with master.

`git fetch && git pull` will do the job for you.

If you have origin and remotes define then go for something like `git pull origin master`.

Answer (score 0):

You should push changes caused by merge. `git push` will do the job, also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10169382/10022404) may be helpful