# What is the difference from HEAD, HEAD^, and HEAD~1?

Tags: git

In git, what is the difference between the following?

- `HEAD`
- `HEAD^`
- `HEAD~1`
- `HEAD~2`

And how do they relate to `master`? So is there a `MASTER^`, `MASTER~1`??

Comment: Please refer to the syntax reference at, for example, http://jk.gs/gitrevisions.html

Comment: you can find info here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221658/whats-the-difference-between-head-and-head-in-git

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between HEAD^ and HEAD~ in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221658/whats-the-difference-between-head-and-head-in-git)

Comment: Let's not forget `HEAD@{1}`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`HEAD` is a synonym for the most recent commit on your current branch, whatever it is.

`HEAD^` (or `HEAD^1`) means the first parent of `HEAD`. A merge commit has multiple parents, so `HEAD^2` refers to the second *immediate* parent of `HEAD` that was involved in the merge that created `HEAD`.

`HEAD~1` is the same as `HEAD~`. In this case, it is synonymous with `HEAD^`. To see the difference, consider that `HEAD~2` is the grandparent of `HEAD`. Using `~` goes back generations.

If you happen to be on the `master` branch, then `HEAD` refers to master. If you are on branch `topic/foo`, then it refers to that branch while you are on it.

Case matters with git. `MASTER^` or `MASTER~1` is likely to produce errors of the form

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'MASTER~1': unknown revision or path not
in the working tree.
```

But `master^` and `master~1` *are* meaningful.

See the [`git rev-parse` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-parse.html) for full details of the many ways you can address commits.