# what are different ways between we git diff?

Tags: git, git-diff

what is the difference between `git diff HEAD^ HEAD` or `git diff HEAD~ HEAD` and this `git diff HEAD^1` or `git diff HEAD~1`?

I understand the ones `git diff HEAD^ HEAD` = `git diff HEAD~ HEAD`.

and so is `git diff HEAD^1` = `git diff HEAD~1` ..

are all these diff yielding same output in any case?

Comment: both answers seems equally awesome don't want to do injustice with anyone of you guys... whose should i accept..?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the main confusion isn't about `git diff` but about `HEAD` and `HEAD^[num]` and `HEAD~[num]`.

**EDIT:**

`HEAD` means the current branch you are working at.

And `HEAD^[num]` means the num'th parent point of a multi-parent node. For a single parent node, [Commit]^[2 or greater] is an invalid expression. ( And git will warn this by `fatal: ambiguous argument '1f9a20d^2': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.`)

The `HEAD~[num]` means the num'th ancester commit of a commit node. For a merging node, the ancester is the branch branch you were on when you merged.

Ref [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221658/whats-the-difference-between-head-and-head-in-git) and [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2304087/what-is-git-head-exactly) to read more about `HEAD` related.

The following picture shows a several way of using [Ancestry References](http://git-scm.com/book/ch6-1.html#Ancestry-References) in a quite simple situation.
[image: Ancestry-References]

ps. Sincecely apology for previous wrong answer and thanks @torek a lot for correcting it out.

Comment: This is not quite right.  The `^2`, `^3`, etc., syntax refer to the N'th parent in the case of a multi-parent (merge) node.  The `~` syntax refers to the N'th *ancestor*.  Both syntaxes may be applied to *any* node-identifier, including a numeric one.  [bluefeet's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21360401/1256452) is more technically-correct.

Comment: Thanks @torek a lot! You are right and sorry for previous answer with error. See the edit.

Answer (score 4):

Your examples are not equivalent.  If you do not specify a commit to compare against then the diff will contain working tree changes, staged or not.

So, `git diff HEAD^` will include working tree changes in the commit, while `git diff HEAD^ HEAD` will not include working tree changes and will only include the diff between the two commits.

`HEAD^`, `HEAD~`, `HEAD^1`, and `HEAD~1` are all identical.  They all refer to the first parent of the `HEAD` commit.

`HEAD^^`, `HEAD~~`, and `HEAD~2` are identical, they all refer to the first parent of the first parent of the `HEAD` commit.  `HEAD^2` is special - it refers the the second parent of the `HEAD` commit, which is only useful if `HEAD` is a merge commit.

More information here:

http://git-scm.com/book/ch6-1.html#Ancestry-References