# GIT - how do I copy SHA without mouse on OSX?

Tags: macos, git, pbcopy

On OSX, often I go to the `git log` in order to find a commit, usually a few back, copy it with my mouse, then rebase off of that.

How can I do this easily without using my mouse or memorizing it?

Comment: Which platform are you on, and what shell are you using?

Comment: Take a look at xsel(1x), if you are using X.

Comment: OSX, zshell/terminal and main editor VIM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just memorize the first couple letters/numbers.

Git does not need the full hash to rebase, it only needs the first couple characters of it.

For example:

```
git log
```

> commit a64da17d5f674973ead1a0bcf0196f292313893f
>
> commit 11be728caad156d5cb6ce336747aab4e5e3417b0
>
> commit e63760a22b4e5919961e409a66fac09176a574b6
>
> commit 3521260b7d04fc92eaeb9c70fa46999dc1ecda3d
>
> commit ba4868bd6a6b4e9d9a77f66e77be189d37b1ffe8

(minus the extra commit stuff)

Now, lets say you want the second one, `11be728caad156d5cb6ce336747aab4e5e3417b0`
You can simply rebase on the first couple characters.

```
git rebase 11be
```

---

Further info: technically git only needs a unique start of a hash. So in this case, `git rebase 1` would be sufficient because no other commit hashes begin with a 1. However, in extreme cases you might need more than 4-5 characters (Very unlikely)

Also, feel free to use `git log -n` to get only the last n number of commits. By keeping this to a low number, the commit is still usually on your screen when you call rebase, so you have no need to memorize. Just manually copy the first couple characters. Hint: If git flushes the log output once you hit 'q' to quit, you can use the command `git --no-pager log -n` to get the output to "stick".

---

For added info on git and rebase, if you knew you wanted to rebase exactly 4 commits, you could just use the `HEAD` reference. Your current commit is `HEAD` and 1 commit ago is `HEAD~1` etc. For example:

```
git rebase HEAD~4
```

would set `3521260b7d04fc92eaeb9c70fa46999dc1ecda3d` as the new `HEAD` (since we are rebasing on `ba4868bd6a6b4e9d9a77f66e77be189d37b1ffe8`)

Comment: Awesome, this may be the easiest, if memorizing just the first few characters works.

Comment: @wejrowski You dont even have to memorize if your log is small. Added a section at the end of the answer to address this.

Comment: Hmm I'm assuming when you run git log your output sticks to your shell (may not totally understand)? Once I quit the log which opens in less, there's no output there.

Comment: @wejrowski git typically only does that on large logs. Try using `git log -2` and see what happens

Comment: Yeah, still disappears.

Comment: @wejrowski Ok sorry. Your shell has different behaviour then mine.

Comment: @wejrowski if for some reason git uses a pager even for small outputs you can use the `--no-pager` option: `git --no-pager log -2`

Answer (score 7):

On OSX, you can use `pbcopy`.

So to get the SHA1 of your last commit in your clipboard:

```
git log -1 --format="%H" | pbcopy
```

Comment: Hmm, normally I would be doing it like 4 commits back which I would need to count and then write that which seems kind of tedious.. is this what you do?

Comment: With `git log -1 --format="%H` you only get the SHA1 of the last commit. But you can also do it with `git rev-parse HEAD`. So for example to get the SHA1 4 commits back: `git rev-parse HEAD~3` (note that it is 3, not 4).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, very helpful. BTW there is a new line in the string after copied, I used this to remove that one: `git log -1 --format="%H" | tr -d '\n' | pbcopy`

Answer (score 0):

An updated version if you want to check what you're copying

This will copy the short hash. This is version is useful if you need to paste your commit hash into a GitHub comment. [GitHub](https://docs.github.com/en/github/writing-on-github/autolinked-references-and-urls#issues-and-pull-requests) auto links commits (references).

```
git log -1 --format="%h" | pbcopy | echo `git log -1 --format="%h"`
```

This will copy the long hash

```
git log -1 --format="%H" | pbcopy | echo `git log -1 --format="%H"`
```

Answer (score 0):

To copy a commit hash from n number of commits ago, pass it as an argument to the log command.

```
git log HEAD~3 --format="%h" | pbcopy
git log HEAD~3 --format="%H" | pbcopy
```

Replace `HEAD~3` with the number of commits back you want to go. One way to verify you copied the correct hash is to paste it into git show

```
git show <pasted hash>
```

If it's wrong change the parent number accordingly. The higher the number, the further back in history you're going.

Refer to [this SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2222920/9627485) for more info on traversing commit history using tilde `~` and carrot `^`

NOTE: Wasn't sure if I should just reply to wejrowski as a comment but decided to post as another answer to build on previous answers. Thanks to Kuhess and Nick Humrich for the initial answer