# Git: interactive rebase lists incorrect (too many) commits

Tags: git, git-interactive-rebase

When I run `git rebase -i HEAD~2`, it lists 11 commits instead of 2. Why?

What I've done prior to this was:

1. Checked out upstream/branchA
2. Rebased my new local copy of branchA with master
3. Tried to push my local branchA back to upstream

   - Git complained that the branches were out of sync, and to first pull in upstream
4. Pulled upstream/branchA into local branchA
5. Pushed local branchA to upstream/branchA (success)

Comment: While `HEAD~2` means "go back 2", it more specifically means "the *first* parent of the *first* parent", emphasis on "first" because there can be a second parent (or even more).  When you find "extra" commits like this that means there's a merge commit (a 2nd parent) in the mix and you're including the commits on both sides of the merge.

Comment: So…how would one get it to behave "normally" ?

Comment: `HEAD~2^2` I guess? See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221658/whats-the-difference-between-head-and-head-in-git) for more details on `git`'s relative commit notation.

Comment: Depends on the shape of the commit graph and what, precisely, you want to rebase / have as your result.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It depends on how your `git` tree looks like. A *"merge"* commit for instance can have two or more parents. Depending on this, your *commit* can have multiple grandparents.

You probably need to rebase with

```
git rebase -i HEAD^1^2
git rebase -i HEAD^2^1
git rebase -i HEAD^2^2
```

(one of these three).

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12527561/67579) for more details about `git`'s relative commit notation.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I ended up just doing a forced push because, 1. my branch was actually up-to-date (and no-one else was working from the old copy); and 2. I didn't want that weird multi-parent behaviour to persist. If it happens again, tho, I'll try the above. After doing one of the above, will `git rebase -i HEAD~2` return to "normal" ?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by doing a rebase with master first and then for the rest of the commits

```
git rebase master
git rebase -i HEAD~n
```