# HEAD~ vs HEAD^ vs HEAD@{} also known as tilde vs caret vs at sign

Tags: git

HEAD is a pointer at the current branch. I have seen a variety of notations for ancestors of HEAD including

- `HEAD~2`
- `HEAD^2`
- `HEAD@{2}`
- `HEAD~~`
- `HEAD^^`

What does each of the above mean, exactly? Where is the documentation for this?

Comment: http://www.paulboxley.com/blog/2011/06/git-caret-and-tilde

Comment: `git help revisions`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between HEAD^ and HEAD~ in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221658/whats-the-difference-between-head-and-head-in-git)

Answer (score 122, accepted):

From the docs [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection).

- `HEAD~2` : 2 commits older than HEAD
- `HEAD^2` : the second parent of HEAD, if HEAD was a merge, otherwise illegal
- `HEAD@{2}` : refers to the 3rd listing in the overview of `git reflog`
- `HEAD~~` : 2 commits older than HEAD
- `HEAD^^` : 2 commits older than HEAD

---

If HEAD was a merge, then

- **first parent** is the branch into which we merged,
- **second parent** is the branch we merged.

---

Some Combinations and Synonyms

```
First Parent    First Grandparent    Second Parent    Second Grandparent

HEAD~
HEAD^
HEAD~1          HEAD~2               HEAD^2           HEAD^2~        
HEAD^1          HEAD^^                                HEAD^2^
```

Comment: The documentation link is perfect. Git Book v2 has many useful additions to v1.

Comment: `HEAD~0` is the same as `HEAD`, as you would expect. Somewhat confusingly, `HEAD^0` is also the same as `HEAD`.

Comment: To remember which symbol is which, I find it helpful that `^` LOOKS like two branches (at the bottom left and bottom right) **merging** together into one (at the top)

Comment: If the OP (or someone with enough rep for a 1-character edit) sees this, there is now an https version of the git-scm URL linked to in the answer.

Comment: @AJM-Reinstate-Monica updated :thumbs-up:

Answer (score 30):

> git reference suffixes (^N, ~N, @{...})

`ref~` is shorthand for `ref~1` and means the commit's first parent. `ref~2` means the commit's first parent's first parent. `ref~3` means the commit's first parent's first parent's first parent. And so on.

`ref^` is shorthand for `ref^1` and means the commit's first parent. But where the two differ is that `ref^2` means the commit's second parent (remember, commits can have two parents when they are a merge).

The ^ and ~ operators can be combined.

Here's a diagram showing how to reference various commits using HEAD as the starting point.
[image]

[src](http://www.paulboxley.com/blog/2011/06/git-caret-and-tilde)

Answer (score 10):

I count each `~` or `^` to mean "going back one level". If there is a number next to `~` (eg. `~n`), then n acts as a multiplier. If there is a number next to `^` (eg. `^n`), then n is the n'th parent to use (or sideways movement going from left-to-right column position in `git log --graph`).

Example:

```
$ git log --oneline --graph 
*   29392c8 (HEAD -> master, tag: A) A
|\
| * a1ef6fd (tag: C) C
| |
|  \
*-. \   8ae20e9 (tag: B) B
|\ \ \
| | |/
| | *   03160db (tag: F) F
| | |\
| | | * 9df28cb (tag: J) J
| | * 2afd329 (tag: I) I
| * a77cb1f (tag: E) E
*   cd75703 (tag: D) D
|\
| * 3043d25 (tag: H) H
* 4ab0473 (tag: G) G
```

Coordinates for above tags:

```
A =      = A^0
B = A^   = A^1     = A~1
C = A^2
D = A^^  = A^1^1   = A~2
E = B^2  = A^^2
F = B^3  = A^^3
G = A^^^ = A^1^1^1 = A~3
H = D^2  = B^^2    = A^^^2  = A~2^2
I = F^   = B^3^    = A^^3^
J = F^2  = B^3^2   = A^^3^2
```

The `git log --online --graph` output makes it hard to see which commits are on the same level, so here is another presentation (where "A" is the latest commit and older commits are at the top):

```
G   H   I   J
 \ /     \ /
  D   E   F
   \  |  / \
    \ | /   |
     \|/    |
      B     C
       \   /
        \ /
         A
```

(Illustrations excerpted from [What's the difference between HEAD^ and HEAD~ in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221658/whats-the-difference-between-head-and-head-in-git)).

Comment: ^ referring to sideways movement should've been pointed out everywhere. thats the gist of it