# Not able to do git reset to previous commit in travis

Tags: git, continuous-integration, travis-ci, travis-ci-cli, travis-ci-api

While building my code in travis, in the case of failure I want reset HEAD to the previous commit and perform some action. The problem is when in `travis.yml` I do:

```
after_failure:
- git reset --hard HEAD@{1}
```

It always points to the latest commit.

If i do `git reset --hard HEAD 04d24f1` I am getting `fatal: Cannot do hard reset with paths.` and printing hashes for some reason shows letter `m` next to the commit that i tried to reset to

```
1b8bc73 (HEAD, origin/feature/RXM-73-create-aws-rollback-script, feature/RXM-73-create-aws-rollback-script) Fail 7
* 04d24f1m Pass 7  << letter m added
* 8c6a51e Fail 6
* 37e3e38 Pass 6
```

If i print history of commits by `git reflog -4`, then I get only 2 commits and they both have the same hash

```
1b8bc73 (HEAD, origin/feature/RXM-73-create-aws-rollback-script, feature/RXM-73-create-aws-rollback-script) HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from feature/RXM-73-create-aws-rollback-script to 1b8bc736d2297be68e18d13de74dde3f75694072
1b8bc73 (HEAD, origin/feature/RXM-73-create-aws-rollback-script, feature/RXM-73-create-aws-rollback-script) HEAD@{1}: clone: from https://github.com/MaxRepo/terraform-rx-manager-service.git
```

If i print history of commits by `git log --oneline --graph --decorate`, then it displays the history like this:

```
* 1b8bc73 (HEAD, origin/feature/RXM-73-create-aws-rollback-script, feature/RXM-73-create-aws-rollback-script) Fail 7
* 04d24f1m Pass 7
* 8c6a51e Fail 6
* 37e3e38 Pass 6
* 4ddfd89 Pass 5
```

Additional info - 
At the beginning this is what travis doing before running commands:

```
0.74s$ git clone --depth=50 --branch=feature/RXM-73-create-aws-rollback-script https://github.com/MaxRepo/terraform-rx-manager-service.git MaxRepo/terraform-rx-manager-service
Cloning into 'MaxRepo/terraform-rx-manager-service'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 118, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (118/118), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (91/91), done.
remote: Total 175 (delta 52), reused 61 (delta 22), pack-reused 57
Receiving objects: 100% (175/175), 32.98 KiB | 8.24 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (66/66), done.
$ cd MaxRepo/terraform-rx-manager-service
$ git checkout -qf 1b8bc736d2297be68e18d13de74dde3f75694072
```

Do you know why i'm not able to `get reset` while building on Travis?

Comment: What about `git reset --hard HEAD~1`?

Comment: @SajibKhan thanks a lot for suggestion. It did work, your answer is correct. I was thinking `git reset --hard HEAD@{1}` will do the same thing. Need to research what is difference between them.

Comment: The problem with `git reset --hard HEAD 04d24f1` is that there are two commits listed: `HEAD` is one, `04d24f1` is the other. You want either the sha1, like `04d24f1`, or something based on `HEAD`, but not both. So `git reset --hard 04d24f1` should have also worked.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26785118/head-vs-head-vs-head-also-known-as-tilde-vs-caret-vs-at-sign

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As already pointed out by Sajib Khan, you want
>
> ```
> git reset --hard HEAD~1
> ```
>
> and not `git reset --hard HEAD@{1}`.

---

There is some useful information [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#gitrevisions-emltrefnamegtltdategtemegemmasteryesterdayememHEAD5minutesagoem), that explains the difference. *In short, `HEAD`, in your case never pointed anywhere other than `(HEAD, origin/feature/RXM-73-create-aws-rollback-script, feature/RXM-73-create-aws-rollback-script)`, and `@` notation is for where head *was* *.

You can investiagte the list of possible `@{#}` values by looking at

[`git reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog)

in order to verify that `HEAD` did not point elsewhere.