# How can I show the history that changed files at specify hash using git command?

Tags: bash, git, command-line, command

I can show the history that changed files at specify hash using Github or Git Tools(SourceTree, SmartGit).

How can I show the history that changed files at specify hash using Git command?

[image: Github]

Comment: `git show <hash>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show the commit SHAs which have affected a given file with [`git-log`](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-log) and show those changes with [`git-show`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show) as @joanis suggests:

```sh
git log <path>

git show <hash> <path>
```

You may also show this output using [`git-diff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff). This might be more helpful if you would like to see the changes on a file over multiple commits rather than a single one at the cost of being more verbose:

```sh
# changes made by the commit
git diff <hash>~ <hash> <path>

# changes made by the commit and the previous one
git diff <hash>~2 <hash> <path>
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26785118/head-vs-head-vs-head-also-known-as-tilde-vs-caret-vs-at-sign) for more info about referencing previous commits

Comment: `git show` is basically an alias for `git log -1 --patch`, the shortest rendition for a single commit would be `git log -1 -m -p -- path`, with `-m` to get the patch even for merges.