# What does '@{1}' means? How is it different from 'HEAD@{1}'?

Tags: git

I noticed that the `@`, `~`, and `^` sign can be combined with many things, like `HEAD`, sha-1, branch names and tags. I also found that `@{number}` can be used alone without being prefixed by `HEAD`. `HEAD@{number}` is used to display an entry in the shortlog. It seems that `@{number}` means the same thing, but I cannot find occurrences of `@{number}` in the docs.

- Is `@{number}` as strict synonym of `HEAD@{number}`?
- Is there other kind of things that can be combined with those sigils?
- Is this documented somewhere?

Relevant links:

- [HEAD~ vs HEAD^ vs HEAD@{} also known as tilde vs caret vs at sign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26785118/head-vs-head-vs-head-also-known-as-tilde-vs-caret-vs-at-sign)
- [official doc: revision selection](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does the "at" @ sign/symbol/character mean in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17910096/what-does-the-at-sign-symbol-character-mean-in-git)

Comment: Yes, it does, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

From the [doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/revisions#Documentation/revisions.txt-emltngtemegem1em) :

> **`@{<n>}, e.g. @{1}`**
> You can use the @ construct with an empty ref part to get at a reflog entry of the current branch. For example, if you are on branch blabla then @{1} means the same as blabla@{1}.

(But this whole revisions page is going through a lot of other syntaxes, be sure to scroll through them, it's a treasure trove!)

Comment: Thanks, it’s what I was searching for. I didn’t realized that there is both https://git-scm.com/book and https://git-scm.com/docs.