# How do I change a remote commit message of an very old commit in GIT with rebase

Tags: git, github

I have an old commit message that I want to edit,
but in rebase I can get only the last 35 commands

Comment: Where did you take that 35 commands limit? I have never heard of it. And I just tested with rebase 60 commits back with no problem.

Comment: I write: "git rebase -i HEAD~60" and get "fatal: Needed a single revision"

Comment: I suggest you try `HEAD^60` - There is a difference. You can read about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221658/whats-the-difference-between-head-and-head-in-git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summary of solution:

OP used `git rebase -i HEAD~60` to locate the commit to rebase on.

The correct way to use it is:

```
git rebase -i HEAD^60
```

It is worth reading the difference between `~` and `^` in: [What's the difference between HEAD^ and HEAD~ in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221658/whats-the-difference-between-head-and-head-in-git)

Answer (score 0):

Locate the commit you want to change message for and copy it's SHA-1. Then do `git rebase -i <SHA-1>~1`.