# Git branch is in an inconsistent state due to a bad merge

Tags: git, github

I have a git branch which started to exhibit the inability to do even trivial rebases going back past a certain point, claiming that many commits had just vanished - and in debugging that issue, I found a simpler anomaly.

`git log` gives me a perfectly consistent list of the commits I expect to see.  And if I use `git reset --hard HEAD^` to move backwards in the commits one at a time, everything works as expected - until suddenly I just back over a dozen commits with no warning at all.

I start from [this commit](https://github.com/rec/BiblioPixel/commits/x-inconsistent-branch) with ID 367df61041c380b3e769177779cb7c8ab21630b4, and a git log that looks like:

```
367df61 fixing flake8/syntax errors
14210b8 Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/dev' into dev
a6818d5 Merge pull request #55 from rec/fast-gamma
e8ffdf2 Tweak exit manager code (fix #56).  Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
d1c464c Tweak masterBrightness.
975de68 Re-enable timedata end-to-end.
bf7e918 Add optional timedata.Renderer to driver_base.py.
b4daff6 Simplify _render slightly.
a306798 Stop slicing colors and add an offset instead.
b379f21 Move generate_header into util.
e50ec8c Simplify frame rendering slightly.
12cfc2d Extract data and functions into return_codes.py
764e4b9 Convert LDP8806.py from DOS line endings to Unix.
d3dc333 Remove old gamma tables.
5ae2934 Simplify gamma.py; prove backward compatibility.
bae1cf4 Temporarily disable timedata and simplify rendering.
c436f19 showing timedata usage
5228261 updating colors.py for py3
```

If I execute `git reset --hard HEAD^` one time, I move to `14210b8 Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/dev' into dev`, as I expect, and the `git log` is consistent with the above.

But now, if I execute `git reset --hard HEAD^` a *second* time, I move to `c436f19 showing timedata usage`, near the bottom of the above list!  All commits between `a6818d5` and `bae1cf4` inclusive just vanish.

My suspicious eye is drawn to the commit [a6818d5a2](https://github.com/rec/BiblioPixel/commit/a6818d5a2bb1ca1e7144cd0d2a4e459ec7182e56) which seems to include all those vanished changes.

How did this happen?  Perhaps by merging from the wrong base branch or commit ID... but exactly what did we do wrong?

Left to my own devices, I'd revert to some known good commit, and then cherry-pick commits one at a time, skipping the merge completely.  It wouldn't be huge amounts of work but I feel there must be a better way.

1. What's going on?  Is this a reasonable state for a branch to be in, and I'm making a mistake using git, or is something "broken"?
2. If it's broken, how do I fix it?  And how do we change our workflow to avoid breaking a branch again?
3. If it isn't broken, how do we change our git workflow to handle this case?

My answer to 3. - disallow merge commits.

All of these boil down to the single question - given that I have these merges, how do I rebase over them?

Comment: @matt: the hat / caret suffix means specifically the *first* parent, unless you add a number. `HEAD^` and `HEAD^1` are both parent #1, and `HEAD^2` is parent #2. If you have an octopus merge (more than 2 parents) this continues on with `HEAD^3` and so forth. The actual order of parent commits is hard to observe with most tools (though some graphical viewers use line colors: the same color, when going past a merge, means "parent #1") but is specified: the first parent is the branch you were "on" (as in, `git status` says "on branch master") when you did the merge.

Answer (score 0):

> What's going on? Is this a reasonable state for a branch to be in, and I'm making a mistake using git, or is something "broken"?

Remember that `git log` shows a linear list of commits by default. This can be a bit confusing in the case of merges because a merge commit has more than one parent. You can use the `git log --oneline --graph` to see the commit graph. It will include extra visualization to help you see all of the parents of each commit.

> If it isn't broken, how do we change our git workflow to handle this case?

I'm new enough to git that I'm not sure about the behavior of `HEAD^` when a commit has more than one parent. This is actually the root of your problem as you reset your way back through the commit history. Also, I don't know about the behavior of `git rebase` when the commit range contains merges. You will need to do some research about both of these issues.

Comment: So you don't actually know the answer. This is actually just a (long) comment.

Comment: @matt IMO, this is an answer, albeit incomplete. Perhaps my edit makes it more clear which part of the OP I am attempting to answer.

Comment: `git log --oneline --graph` at least makes it graphically clear what the issue is.

Answer (score -1):

First, make sure in what status your working copy is with `git status`. You can get very surprising results when you forgot about a merge, rebase, bisect or other conflict situations.

Then, don't use `git reset --hard` when the current HEAD is still important. Use `git checkout <hash>` to move where you want and tag the commit there or open a branch there with `git checkout -b <branchname> <hash>`. All these safer commands will prevent that you lose `HEAD` by accident.

I have not seen yet that `HEAD^` points to something else than the (first) parent commit. You can find a nice explanation for these kinds of navigation methods [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2221658/6769270). But when you are not absolutely sure then look up what `HEAD^` is with `git log HEAD^`.

Just in case you lost your `HEAD`, maybe you can still find the old commits with `git reflog` if the garbage collector has not done its work, yet.

Comment: What!?  I haven't lost my HEAD - I haven't lost any work.  Everything is fine;  I'm just trying to debug what's wrong with this branch that prevents me from rebasing it.

Comment: You haven't explained in what state the working copy is and you haven't answered any question by other people how the merge graph looks like. You wrote your commits have vanished. I just wanted to help.

Comment: Just because something unexpected happens when I rebase, doesn't mean I actually lose work!  I was trying to debug a branch which was impossible to rebase through.  No one did actually ask to see the merge graph - but yes, the problem is that merge commits have two parents.  Still no idea how to rebase over them and preserve them, though...

Comment: There is not much information to help you. I cannot tell why the merge is "bad" as you called it. Are there commits that don't belong there? Or do you just want to have a linear history?

Comment: Or maybe you cannot restore the state before the merge (= roll back the branch back to the previous point containing just your commits)?