# How to get a parent commit id for a given commit?

Tags: git

I have a commit, which was merged in such a way that git log is a mess.
I want to know which commit is a parent to a given commit, i.e., what was the working area state before that commit was merged.

I've tried to use `commit_id~1` as 'previous', but I failed. How can I get 'previous commit' in git?

Comment: Please explain in more detail what "but I failed" means. Show the exact output from the session.

Comment: It's easy to do with VS2017, or SourceTree, or bithucket, do you *have* to use the command line?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221658/whats-the-difference-between-head-and-head-in-git for tips on referring to ancestors of a given commit.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the hashes, two equivalent choices:

```
 git log --pretty=%P -n 1 <commit>
 git show --pretty=%P <commit>
```