# git reset --soft "HEAD^6" what does it means?

Tags: git, git-reset

I ran `git reset --soft "HEAD^6"` by mistake on my local repo after that I ran `git reset --soft "HEAD^"`

Now i can find more than 100 file with local changes

What `git reset --soft "HEAD^6"` does it mean ?

**Edit:** for those who will ask why i did that, it was a typo.

Comment: Did `git reset --soft "HEAD^6"` succeed? I'm asking because `HEAD^6` means the 6th parent of `HEAD`. It has little chance to be a valid ref as an octopus merge with as many as 6 branches is very rare. Maybe a typo of `HEAD~6`?

Comment: @MeladEzzat Can you show the output you had on the command? Sorry to doubt your word, but I find it unlikely that you had anything else than "fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD^6': unknown revision or path not in the working tree." Isn't it the case?

Comment: @ElpieKay and RomainValeri, you are correct it wasn't successful, it was "fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD^6': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:". but still i have more than 100 changed file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**About `reset --soft`**

`git reset --soft <commitHash>` will move `HEAD` without changing the state of your files ([doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset#Documentation/git-reset.txt---soft)).

That's why `git status` suddenly *sees* differences. It now compares your (unchanged) code with an older reference. But your files did **not** change when you did the two last operations.

---

**About the refspec `HEAD^6`**

`HEAD^6` will *try to* point to the 6th parent of `HEAD` commit. This will fails in most situations. That is, unless your `HEAD` commit is the result of an (at least) 6-headed octopus merge. I guess we can rule this out.

---

**Conclusion**

So the second operation failed and was a no-op. If your first reset was intended, you're good to go!

Answer (score 2):

As others mentioned it changes HEAD to the 6th parent. To go back to the previous state you can reset to the your remote with `git reset --hard origin/<branch>`. If you haven't pushed out your changes look at `git reflog` then do `git reset --hard <sha>`.

Comment: I was about to add that also, but then I realized... OP didn't state that the first `reset` was unwanted, and the *second one* wasn't actually performed. So no `reset` necessary at this point.

Answer (score -1):

git reset --soft "HEAD^6" reverts last 6 commits into working dir.
if your changes are pushed into remote you can come back to previous state by `git reset --hard origin/<<branch>>`

Comment: Did you confuse `HEAD^6` with `HEAD~6`? The latter *will* point back 6 commits, but not the former.

Comment: @RomainValeri explanation for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221658/whats-the-difference-between-head-and-head-in-git

Comment: "Explanation for me"?! I precisely explained it already in my answer, then I repeated the idea to *you* in my comment, and even then you did *not* apply what you're linking here. I'm confused, what did I miss?