# What does the ~ mean after the branch of a git rebase --onto?

Tags: git, rebase, git-rewrite-history

In the example that the Git docs give for `git rebase --onto` its not clear about what the ~ means

> A range of commits could also be removed with rebase. If we have the following situation:
>
> `enter code here E---F---G---H---I---J  topicA`
>
> then the command
>
> `git rebase --onto topicA~5 topicA~3 topicA`
>
> would result in the removal of commits F and G:
>
> `E---H'---I'---J'  topicA`
>
> This is useful if F and G were flawed in some way, or should not be part of topicA. Note that the argument to --onto and the  parameter can be any valid commit-ish.

Does `topicA~5` mean 5 commits from the head of `topicA`? (So counting backwards?)

I cant think of anything else that it would mean but I want to be sure before i try it on my repo.

Comment: Yes, five commits before topicA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is from [git rev-parse](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse#Documentation/git-rev-parse.txt-emltrevgtltngtemegemmaster3em)

> ```
> <rev>~<n>, e.g. master~3
> ```
>
> A suffix `~<n>` to a revision parameter means the commit object that is the `<n>`th generation ancestor of the named commit object, following only the first parents.
> I.e. `<rev>~3` is equivalent to `<rev>^^^` which is equivalent to `<rev>^1^1^1`.

So in your case, yes, `topicA~5` mean 5 commits from the head of `topicA`: commit `E`.

Answer (score 0):

`~` Means the parent of a commit, so `hash~5` is the grand-grand-grand-grand-parent of `hash`.

Graphically, it can be seen like that (output similar to `git log --graph --oneline`, oldest commit at the bottom):

```
* ggggg - (HEAD)
* fffff
* eeeee
* ddddd
* ccccc
* bbbbb
* aaaaa
```

Then:

```
ggggg~5 == bbbbb
```

I gave a more in depth explanation of `~` and `^` in this response: [Git what is the logical difference between parent and ancestor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55607027/git-what-is-the-logical-difference-between-parent-and-ancestor/55607435#55607435)