# In Git go back one commit temporarily to create a branch and then reapply the commit to master branch

Tags: git, github

I have always worked with git and opensrc in a very simple limited way

- I *fork* the project in *github*
- I *git clone* my fork to my computer
- I make some changes on my computer
- I *commit* the changes
- I *push* to my github fork
- I created *pull request* from my *github* fork to the original project, this works for a single change

But if I make more changes on my computer and commit them and push before the pull request is accepted then they get added to the same pull request. I know this is not ideal so I try and wait for first pull request to be accepted before making further changes but this is not always possible.

So instead I experimented with creating a new branch just to fix one bug. But because this branch was  created after I had already made a commit on the master branch any pull requests on this new branch include my master commit as well.

So want I think what I want to do is **temporarily go back one commit on master branch, then create new branch, then go forward to that commit on master branch, how do I do that** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `git branch new_branch` creates a new branch using the current `HEAD`. To choose a different starting point, simply provide it explicitly.

```
git branch new_branch HEAD^
```

Comment: where HEAD^ is a commit id ?

Comment: `HEAD^` is the parent of the currently checked-out branch head. It's not just a placeholder; it's a valid reference to a specific commit.

Comment: I dont understand,

Comment: Assuming you have added exactly one commit to your `master` branch, the command shown in this answer, typed exactly as is, will create a new branch based on `master` as it was before your commit.

Comment: OK, thanks, for completeness can I also specify a commitid instead ?

Comment: Yes, you can specify any commit id you like. `HEAD^` just happens to be one way to specify the commit id you were asking about.

Comment: HEAD~ vs HEAD^... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221658/whats-the-difference-between-head-and-head-in-git