# How to determine which parent is the first one for a merge commit in Git

Tags: git, git-merge, git-commit

I was reading about the difference in using a `~` vs `^` operator in git and I came across this question [What's the difference between HEAD^ and HEAD~ in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2221658/2498327)

The one thing I could not find a good explanation for online after googling is how does git distinguish the first parent of a merge commit from the second one?

Is there a rule of thumb?

Take this example where a `feature` branch is merged **into** the `develop` branch, creating the merge commit `G`.

```
develop feature/foo
     A   D
     |   |
     B   E
     |   |
     C   F
      \ /
       G <- develop(HEAD)
```

Which one is the first parent of `G`? `C` or `F`? Why is it the first parent?

NOTE: This is not a request for the git command to determine the first or the second parent. I'm aware that it can be achieved using `git show G^1` and `git show G^2`. I see that `C` is the first parent of `G` and `F` is the second parent. But, I do not understand why that is the case. Is it like the branch on which the merge commit is made determines the first parent?

Comment: I suppose first is this which you merge to. It is not in docs, we must check source code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is it like the branch on which the merge commit is made determines the
> first parent?

Yes.

Referring to [Git-Tools-Revision-Selection](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection) of Pro Git :

> You can also specify a number after the ^ to identify which parent you
> want; for example, d921970^2 means “the second parent of d921970.”
> This syntax is useful only for merge commits, which have more than one
> parent — the first parent of a merge commit is from the branch you
> were on when you merged (frequently master), while the second parent
> of a merge commit is from the branch that was merged (say, topic):

And commands like `git show G^1`, `git show G^2`, `git log -1 --pretty=%P G`, and `git rev-parse G^@`, can prove it's the same as described. Besides, use `git cat-file -p G` to inspect the content of the commit object, and we can see the parents are recorded in the order.

Answer (score 2):

**The first parent is *usually* the `HEAD` commit of the branch on which you perform the merge.**

`git commit` uses the `HEAD` commit as the first parent (if there's no conflict, `git merge` will do the commit for you, or else you do it yourself. Same result either way).  All the convenience commands follow this convention. You can build arbitrary commits yourself with `git commit-tree` and specify any parents you like, for any reason.

Answer (score -3):

So, there is no parent of the commit as such. But you can say which one is the parent depending on the branch from which you ran the `git merge`

Comment: Every commit has at least 1 parent. Merge commits have 2 or more.