# What does `HEAD~1` mean in `git reset --hard HEAD~1`?

Tags: git

So basically I want to revert the previous 6 commits and leave the history. Basically resetting the log back to 6 commits ago.

Let's say I have git commits:

```
HEAD -> 1231513123151
        1231513123152
        1231513123153
        1231513123154
        1231513123155
        1231513123156
        8172382173817 <---- I want to point the HEAD here and throw all the up commits.
```

Does this mean I have to use `git reset --hard HEAD~6`?

Or is there a better way to do this? Or should I just do the `git reset --hard HEAD~1` 6 times?

Comment: >"git reset --hard HEAD~6" Yes, using numbers other than 1 is valid. Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221658/whats-the-difference-between-head-and-head-in-git

Comment: `HEAD~1` means _one_ commit prior to the current HEAD, and so forth with `HEAD~2` onwards.

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions

Comment: Thanks so much, all! That helped! I almost forgot to reply here.