# What is the difference between reset HEAD and HEAD~?

Tags: git

I understand that by default unless a previous commit is checked-out, `HEAD` is the latest commit on the currently checked-out branch.

What is the difference between:

- `git reset HEAD`
- `git reset HEAD~`

My understanding:

The first command will reset latest commit - why would anyone do this? Unless for example `HEAD` is made to point to another place using checkout command prior to running this reset command. Correct?

The second command will reset the commit prior to the head, effectively the latest commit will now be orphaned. Correct?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the difference between HEAD^ and HEAD~ in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221658/whats-the-difference-between-head-and-head-in-git)

Comment: No commit will be destroyed, with either command. The first one will *unstage* everything. The second one will also make current branch point one commit "back", following ancestry (so current commit's parent.

Comment: @Edric Not convinced it's a close enough duplicate, because of `git reset HEAD` which is not adressed.

Comment: I don't know about `git reset HEAD`, but `git reset --hard HEAD` (or simply `git reset --hard`) is terribly important and useful; I say it every day.

Answer (score 3):

`git reset X` is identical to `git reset --mixed X`. Looking at [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset#Documentation/git-reset.txt-emgitresetemltmodegtltcommitgt), that is:

> ###### `git reset [<mode>] [<commit>]`
>
> This form resets the current branch head to `<commit>` and possibly updates the index (resetting it to the tree of `<commit>`) and the
> working tree depending on `<mode>`. If `<mode>` is omitted, defaults to
> `--mixed`. The `<mode>` must be one of the following:
>
> ###### `--mixed`
>
> Resets the index but not the working tree (i.e., the changed files are preserved but not marked for commit) and reports what has
> not been updated. This is the default action.
>
> If `-N` is specified, removed paths are marked as intent-to-add (see [git-add](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add)).

So, `git reset --mixed` resets marks all staged changes as unstaged again. `git reset --mixed HEAD` is identical. `git reset --mixed HEAD^` moves your HEAD back by one (following the first parent).

Executing `git reset HEAD^` will lose the commit that was HEAD at the time this command is executed, *unless it is reachable from other refs (branches, tags)*.

Comment: Ok so `git reset --mixed HEAD` has no impact on the committed things.

Comment: @variable correct. It will move HEAD to HEAD, which is not really moving it :)

Comment: When you are in the middle of a merge, `git reset HEAD` also has an effect on *conflicting files* : it clears the inner conflict flags in the index, which allows you to unlock some other actions. Be aware, though, that you haven't *fixed the conflict* (the content of your file at least), and that your file will still contain conflict markers (`<<<<<<< HEAD`, `>>>>>>> thatothercommit`) and partial chunks from both versions.