# How do I undo a bad commit --amend?

Tags: git

This may sound weird, but I just amended a commit to test my `EDITOR` environment variable. I wasn't aware that the commit would be amended even though I didn't edit the commit message or any files. The commit in question was merged from the develop branch into the master branch and tagged. After the amend though, the branch structure went all wonky:

[image: Screen shot]

I don't know how bad this is or how many issues it will cause in the future, but I don't dare touch the repository until I know more. I'd really like to just rewind the repository back to before I amended the "Added docs." commit. The develop branch should be pointing to the "Added docs." commit that's merged into the master branch, and the current "Added docs." commit should not exist.

Is that possible?

---

Related:

- [How to undo "git commit --amend" done instead of "git commit"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459150/how-to-undo-git-commit-amend-done-instead-of-git-commit)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should be able to do a

```
git reflog
```

Then find out the commit you were in before your “commit --amend”. Usually this would be HEAD@{1}. Now do a

```
git reset --soft HEAD@{1}
```

Comment: Perfect!! In my case it was `HEAD@{6}`.

Comment: Note that this is often easier if you just use gitk. You already know which commit you want to move your head to. Just copy the sha from gitk and run `git reset --soft **SHA**`