# How do I recover from a commit --amend if I already pushed the original commit?

Tags: git

Scenario: I commit, push to the remote server, and then commit something else with --amend.  If I try to push again, I'll get an error because I changed history that was already pushed.

1. Lets say I **don't** care about the amended changes, how do I undo this so my history looks like the remote history (discard the --amend changes)?
2. Lets say I **do** care about the amended changes, how do I turn the amended commit into a stand alone commit so history looks like this:

   ```
          commit 1            <-           commit 2
   (already pushed to server) <- (originally from amended commit)
   ```

I'm trying to avoid having to use a `push -f`.

---

[This is a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459150/how-to-undo-git-commit-amend-done-instead-of-git-commit) but there is a key difference: In that question, he hasn't pushed commit 1 to a remote repo yet.  In my question, I have.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll assume your remote is called `origin`, and your branch is called `master`. Adjust as needed.

> Lets say I don't care about the amended changes

Then you can use `git reset --hard origin/master`. This sets your current branch to exactly what is on the remote, and updates your index and worktree to match.

> Lets say I do care about the amended changes

Then you can use `git reset --soft origin/master`. This sets your current branch to exactly what is on the remote, but does not update your index or worktree to match. You can then use `git commit` to create a new commit containing your added changes.

Comment: So is the second part kind of like saying, "Check out this branch but don't modify anything on the file system"?  That way, you can commit the differences?

Comment: Looking at your answer, it looks like it's essentially the same answer as the question I linked to.  But I didn't understand what the `--soft` was doing until your explanation.  Thanks

Comment: @tieTYT Right, I see now that it is indeed exactly what's in the other question's accepted answer already. If I had noticed that before, I wouldn't have posted this as an answer (but I would have commented so on your question). Regardless, I'm glad it helped.