# How to Undo git commit --amend

Tags: git, git-commit, git-rewrite-history

I've accidently did `git commit --amend` on the last commit on the tree (which is not written by me ) and I would like to undo this `commit` and **retrieve** my changes back to the working directory.

I'm familiar with the fact the `--commit amend` is part of "Rewriting History" Git commands but I hope there is a workaround via author name or any other.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a way to recover your state prior to the amend. 
Go to the working copy and run `git reflog`, find the hash of the commit prior to the amend and do a git reset to it. You are done ;)

Duplicate of: [How to undo "git commit --amend" done instead of "git commit"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459150/how-to-undo-git-commit-amend-done-instead-of-git-commit)