# Can I use the 'Amend last commit' in Git to transfer the changes to another branch?

Tags: git, branch, commit, git-amend

I accidentally made a commit in the wrong branch but since I can do Amend I'm thinking if it's possible to use it to transfer the changes to the right branch. Can I change branch instead and do the amend there or will it be applied to the same branch where it was committed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to undo "git commit --amend" done instead of "git commit"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459150/how-to-undo-git-commit-amend-done-instead-of-git-commit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have not yet pushed the first branch with the mistaken commit, you may try cherry picking it to the right branch, then rolling back the first branch:

```
# switch to correct branch, and cherry-pick desired commit
git checkout branch2
git cherry-pick <SHA-1 of commit>

# then switch to first branch, and remove incorrect commit
git checkout branch1
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

The `<SHA-1>` of the commit you want can be found by using `git log branch1`.  Note that if you have already pushed `branch1`, then a safer option would be to `git revert` that commit.  But, you may still use cherry picking to move the commit to the second branch.

Comment: Thanks very much for the great Answer Tim! I'm more of wondering or trying to discover if there is another way of solving it than the usual way. I forgot to add it to the details of my question hehe. Thanks again!